# Ландшафтні дослідження чи ландшафтознавчі дослідження?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, значення-слів, словосполучення

При написанні доповіді з предмету екології стикнулась з багатьма проблемами. Ці словосполучення - одна з таких проблем, і я не знайшла інформацію по них. Допоможіть, будь ласка.
"Витоки ландшафтних / ландшафтонавчих досліджень в Україні"

Comment: Будь ласка, завжди вказуйте контекст, у якому ця фраза має застосовуватися.

Comment: Витоки ландшафтних \ ландшафтонавчих досліджень в Україні

Comment: Будь ласка, пишіть уточнення не в коментарях (які згодом будуть видалені), а натискайте кнопку [edit] у запитанні і вносьте поправки туди.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вірогідно, що залежить від значення. Може стосуватися досліджень ландшафту чи досліджень ландшафтознавців. В контексті прикладних досліджень - перше, теоретичних - друге.